# jQuery slider if statement rollover image

Tags: jquery, click, slider, rollover

So I have a slider plugin running for a WP driven site, unfortunately through the plugin you can't set rollover/active states with images. I have gotten kind of far with trying to achieve this but can't figure out the rest of the if statement so when you click on the first button it shows the recessed image, then click on the next one the first button goes back to the regular state and the 2nd one goes to the recessed image. Here is my code so far:

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {
jQuery('.thumb1 img, .thumb2 img, .thumb3 img').click(function () {
    var $clicked = jQuery(this);
    jQuery('.thumb1 img, .thumb2 img, .thumb3 img').each(function(){
        var $this = jQuery(this);
        if ($clicked.get(0) === $this.get(0))
            $this.attr('src','/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/new_slide_1_btn_hover.jpg');
        else
            $this.attr('src','/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/new_slide_1_btn.jpg');
    });
}); });
```

Right now every image after the click chagnes to the image used for the 1st butting which isn't correct. There are 3 button to click on each are unique and have their own unique rollover image. Each button has a class of thumb1, thumb2 and thumb3.. any help would be great, I am not a javascript guy but trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a class called `selectable` or whatever you want to call it.

```
<img class="selectable" src="/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/new_slide_1_btn.jpg"/>
```

and this jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $(".selectable").click(function(){
        //make all the default button
        $(".selectable").each(function(){ 
            $(this).attr("src","/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/new_slide_1_btn.jpg");
        });
        //make the just clicked image the hover button
        $(this).attr("src","/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/new_slide_1_btn_hover.jpg");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Update **Michael_B** answer:

```
$(function(){
    $(".selectable").click(function(){
        //make all the default button
        $(".selectable").each(function(){ 
            $(this).attr("src", $(this)[0].src.replace(/_hover(\..*)/, '$1'));
        });
        //make the just clicked image the hover button
        $(this).attr("src",$this[0].src.replace(/(\..*)$/, '_hover$1'));
    });
});
```

Comment: Michael_B is this something I could use for 3 unique active state images? At quick glance this appears to be if I had the same 1 image for the active state for each of the 3 buttons.

Comment: It appears that @Michael Malinovskij has modified the answer to append and remove hover to image names to allow as many images as you might want.